# You do not have Javascript enabled. Javascript is required to use salesforce.com. Please enable Javascript, then click here to continue

Tags: jmeter

in jmeter while recording i sucessfully logined in web application but in view results tree it is showing You do not have Javascript enabled. Javascript is required to use salesforce.com. Please enable Javascript, then click here to continue.  how to solve this..please help

i have correlated dynamic vales,but still getting that error please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if the page you're reaching after successful log in checks if [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) is enabled the check will fail in JMeter because JMeter is not capable of executing client-side JavaScript.

With regards to "sucessfully logined" - it might be the case you are not, JMeter automatically treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as as successful so it worth adding custom pass/fail criteria using i.e. [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter) to ensure that the page you're hitting contains anticipated data or there are no obvious errors in the response

With regards to Salesforce performance testing in general make sure you're allowed to do it because it's SaaS and your tests can impact others work. Check out [Performance test FAQs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387059&type=1) before running full-scale test.